# Not able to send heavy data as json/string from Apex Class to visualforce page from Apex class properties

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a situation where I am using `<apex:actionFunction>` `oncomplete` attribute to call a JS function and i am sending some data as parameters but this data is very heavy, having around 90,000 characters and I am not able to pass it as parameter in actionFunction's oncomplete, actually the JS functin on oncomplete is not getting called.

My actionFunction :

```
<apex:actionFunction name="GetAllData" action="{!GetDataController}" reRender="none" oncomplete="GetProjectCompleted('{!data1}')">
    <apex:param id="userAndDomainProj" name="userAndDomainProj" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

The data I am trying to get from Apex Class is `{!data1}`.
If data1 has small data I am able to fetch it easily and if data is large I am not even able to call function.

What can be the solution.

Is there anty other way to send this heavy data from Apex class to visualforce page.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the issue is not necessarily with data size, rather, the larger data set has a syntax error in it such as a single quote that is causing an issue with the script execution. Do you see any errors in the browser developer console? If so can you make sure you provide that error for us.

Comment: No there was no error in browser's developer console

Comment: When you view the source of the page do you see any data in that part of the source code. The `{!data1}` should be replaced with the raw data you're trying to pass to your JS method. Can you provide a copy of the HTML output including the big data so we can take a look?

Comment: But one thing surely happened that I printed the data in System.Debug and copied the data and pasted it in a string variable and I noticed that it had some special characters which weren't escaped and giving error, but this was the case when I manually pasted the string data. can this be the case?

Comment: That is a very likely cause, the best way to find out is to do what my previous comment says.

Comment: @gNerb is there a way to see it because i am fillig the variable on actionFunction and accessing its value from oncomplete

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure that should work, I'm surprised that you even got it to work with small data. The `{!data1}` should be populated on page load. If you don't re-render it that parameter is never updated to include the value from the controller. There's a lot going on with what you have here that brings up questions. I'm just trying to assume that since you got it to work with small data that there is a different issue.

Comment: @gNerb yeah i got it to work by small data, thats for sure, either big data seems to be the issue or some special characters are causing trouble i guess.

Comment: @gNerb, if I got it to work by small data than what can be the pblm according to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83395/discussion-between-gnerb-and-rrc1709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behavior with "small data" by creating the sample page below:

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController" doctype="html-5.0">
    <apex:form id="none">
        <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunction" action="{!doIt}" reRender="none" oncomplete="alert('{!data}')">
            <apex:param name="param" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    actionFunction('hello world!');
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class testPageController {
    public String data {get; set;}

    public testPageController() {
        this.data = '';
    }

    public void doIt() {
        String param = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param');
        system.debug(param);
        this.data = param;
    }
}
```

To be honest I'm surprised this even works because if you view the source of the page this is what the action function looks like:

```
<script id="j_id0:none:j_id1" type="text/javascript">
    actionFunction=function(param){
        A4J.AJAX.Submit(
            'j_id0:none',
            null,
            {
                'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:none:j_id1',
                'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){
                    alert('')
                },
                'parameters':{
                    'param':(typeof param!='undefined'&&param!=null)?param:'',
                    'j_id0:none:j_id1':'j_id0:none:j_id1'
                 } 
             } 
         )
     };
</script>
```

Notice the alert has an empty string parameter. The fact that my page can actually alert the "hello world" even though that parameter renders as empty even after the form is re-rendered is what surprises me.

Anyway, since this works my only conclusion is the one I mentioned in the comments. there must be something in the string that is causing a syntax error. This is verified by the fact that you said when you copy/paste the debug into the script and run it you get errors.

I was also able to replicate your issue where there are no developer console errors by manually setting the value of data to `'\'test'` in the apex code:

```
 public void doIt() {
    this.data = '\'test';
}
```

doing this actually allows the HTML to render the attribute:

```
alert(''test')
```

In which there is the very obvious syntax error, but this does not throw any developer console errors for a reason I can't ascertain.

### Conclusion

Something in `{!data1}` is causing a syntax error.

Comment: In this case how can special characters be handled, as here it can be seen that you have escaped the quote but still it gives error

Comment: I think it depends on your data, the safest bet would be to remove the characters altogether. You can also consider doing a `string.replace(data1, '\'', '"')` to replace all single quotes with double quotes if you think that makes sense for your data.

Comment: You could also consider `JSON.serialize(data1)` to convert it into a properly formatted json string and then pass the json directly to your method by removing the single quotes `oncomplete="alert({!data})"` but again, that depends on your data.

Comment: will try it out and let you know.Thnx for ur suggestions.It helped me understand the root cause

Comment: There is one more solution, and that is to use JavaScript remoting or the SFDC javascript apis to handle the bulk of the work in JS. I can't help but feel that  your issue here is that you're taking advantage of a behavior that probably shouldn't work at all. There's a risk of this getting "fixed" breaking your code.

Comment: JavaScript remoting worked for me and its easier to use than calling oncomplete and stuff. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's great news, please remember to accept the answer.